# Paragraph ended before \pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@NEXT@WITH@ERRORRANGE@ was complete

Tags: pgfplots

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\definecolor{beaublue}{rgb}{.74, .83, .9}
\definecolor{electriclavender}{rgb}{.96, .73, 1.0}
\definecolor{classicrose}{rgb}{.98, .8, .91}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    %   \begin{tikzpicture}[scale =.6, transform shape]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[   
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar = 2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel={Average Reliability},
    symbolic x coords={RABFD, EABFD, REABFD, OLB},
    xtick=data, 
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    ymin=0,
    %ymajorgrids,
    %yminorgrids,
    minor y tick num=5, 
    xlabel style={yshift=-.3cm},
    ylabel style={yshift=-.3cm},
    %   xticklabel style={rotate=90},
    %width=1*\textwidth,
    %height=9cm,    
    %ytick={0,200,400,600,800,1000,1200,1400},      
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    legend style={at={(.5,-0.1)}, anchor=north, /tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=.5cm}},
    legend columns = -1,    
    %nodes near coords,
    %nodes near coords align={vertical},
    ]
    %\addplot[style = {bblue, fill=blue, mark=none, postaction={pattern=grid}}]
    \addplot[style = {fill = classicrose, mark=none, postaction={pattern=dots}}, error bars/.cd]    
        coordinates {
        (RABFD, 0.970719598) +- (.06317) 
        (EABFD, 0.962698536) +- (.064793) 
        (REABFD, 0.96500492) +- (.04826) 
        (OLB,0.428926) +- (.0351795)};
    %coordinates {(RABFD, 0.970719598) (EABFD, 0.962698536) (REABFD, 0.96500492) (OLB,0.428926) };  
    %\addplot[style = {rred, fill=rred, mark=none, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}]
    \addplot[style = {fill=beaublue, mark=none, postaction={pattern=north east lines}}, error bars/.cd]
    coordinates {
        (RABFD, 0.96096607) +-(.05316954) 
        (EABFD, 0.9358501)  +-(.0889955) 
        (REABFD, 0.9614802) +-(.06466) 
        (OLB, 0.432586) +-(.0338931)};  
    %coordinates {(RABFD, 0.96096607) (EABFD, 0.9358501) (REABFD, 0.9514802) (OLB, 0.432586)};
    \legend{Checkpointing, Without Checkpointing}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Total Reliability}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a full minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)). Your codes does not conatin `\documentclass` and `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks. It is a big document and I am getting problem in this specific section.

Comment: Please read the given MWE link carefully! You just have to add a minimal working example and not your whole document. The given code should be compilable for us.

Comment: I have changed the code. Now it will able to be compiled. But still facing the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct syntax for specifying the error?

Comment: Probably not. If you search the macro in the title in the source code, you find the definition `\def\pgfplots@foreach@plot@coord@NEXT@WITH@ERRORRANGE@#1,#2){...}`, which suggests that you should write `+-(0,.06)` instead of `+-(.06)`.

Comment: Note also that all the examples in the manual has both an x- and a y-value for the error, even if just one is used.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.